How to italicize a portion of a plot label while keeping the sans-serif font?
Currently I have this:
Current plot
I would only like a portion of a label, say c/R_p [-], to be italicized.
This is what I do in MATLAB to get the above upper x-label:
xlabel(ax2, '{\fontfamily{cmss}\selectfont Chord $\mathsf{c/R_p} \, \textsf[-]$}', 'Interpreter', 'latex');

I tried combining \mathsf with \mathit, but, depending on who I use first, either I get no italics or I get italics but in the standard latex font (hence, I lose sans-serif).
I know this can be done somehow, as here they managed to do it:
What I'm trying to achieve
Thanks for your help!

In the example you give, isn't the text serif?

@magnesium you mean the second image? I believe it is CMU Sans Serif, I also checked on Word

Both of your images ("current plot" and "what I'm trying to achieve") are using fonts with serifs, CMU Sans Serif looks pretty different. Do you care about rendering a specific font, or the italics, or both?

@Wolfie, thank you, I just realized. I would like like a portion of a label, say c/R_p [-], to be italicized while keeping the serif font, exactly as in "What I'm trying to achieve").

With the tex interpreter, you can just use the \it{} command to make italic text:
xlabel( 'Radial Coordinate \it{c/R}', 'Interpreter', 'tex' );
ylabel( 'Pitch Angle \beta [deg]', 'Interpreter', 'tex' );

Note that this uses a sans-serif font (the default font for non-tex labels).

Alternatively you can use the latex interpreter which gives you more powerful LaTeX rendering. Note that LaTeX-rendered equations are in italics by default, so just having your italic characters as inline equations like $this$ will cause them to be italicised. The default LaTeX font will be used, which has serifs.
xlabel( 'Radial Coordinate $c/R$', 'Interpreter', 'latex' );
ylabel( 'Pitch Angle $\beta$ [deg]', 'Interpreter', 'latex' );



Thanks for your answer. I would use tex instead of latex as interpreter if it wasn't for the fact that subscripts are too low and give an ugly look to the equation. Apparently there's no way of using latex as interpreter while still keeping the sans-serif font. Since I need this plot for a LaTeX document, I'd better add the labels on LaTeX by using some dedicated package I suppose

@floyd In your "what I'm trying to achieve" plot you don't have any subscripts, the scope of what you're asking keeps moving, and in a comment you said you'd like to keep the serif font exactly as in that image which is what the LaTeX interpreter gives you. Sorry I don't think I understand why you've gone back to asking for sans-serif fonts when you previously confirmed the opposite.

My apologies, let me clarify. I need the font that is used in the "what I'm trying to achieve" plot while also using LaTeX as interpreter. I need to use LaTeX as interpreter because in my plot ("current plot") I use subscripts

@floyd OK, so what's wrong with my 2nd example plot which uses the LaTeX interpreter and has both "upright" and italic fonts, all with serif fonts as in your desired example?

The font of your 2nd example looks different from the one in "what I'm trying to achieve"

OK, I think maybe the title of this question threw things off because the core issue seems  unrelated to sans-serif or italicised fonts, and rather just How to use LaTeX fonts in MATLAB

Unfortunately that doesn't help. I looked into this problem deeper online and it looks like MATLAB doesn't allow doing what I'm trying to do
